# Dividing a CakePHP project into 2 huge sub-systems

Tags: cakephp

I am working in a huge project, in CakePHP. Its tough to handle a huge system like this. So, I want to divide this system into 2 sub-systems. There will be same database, with same tables. Both sub-systems can use all the tables. I just want to make 2 packages of Controllers, Models, Views; I mean, both package will have their own Controller, Models, Views, and they may interact if they need to.

Its like HMVC of Code Igniter, triads of MVCs.

Is that possible ? If yes, how ? I am asking for any code, I am asking for the way to organize my system(site) in a systematic way.

Thanks.

Comment: what about creating two plugins?

Comment: I think plugins is your answer. Make them load with composer and you are set. we do the same at our company for some hug sub-systems (tools) that depends on the main app. The main app can function without them, but the plugin can't function without the main app. It gives you some great control over your submodules. When a submodule contains over 10 models, it gives you that extra overview.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am now trying to make a plugin.@Jelmer

Comment: Plugins can work without any 'main app', all plugins require is CakePHP core (and any external dependency that was specifically coded into the plugin).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of HMVC in Cake would be the plugins. You can make as much plugins as you like in order to modularize your project.

Although making your code modular (using plugins) is good, you need to keep the reference to the plugins in the rest of the site/project.

As example you always need to place plugin in the link in order to keep the proper links like

```
$this->Html->link('Your link', array('plugin'=>'my-plugin', 'controller'=>'my-controller',....));
```

Apart from that I think there are a lot of benefits making your project modular.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped my purpose.@Nik Chankov